# Is there a guarantee that ActiveRecord returns objects ordered by ID?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

My project is hosted on Heroku.
I was surprised when `Room.all` method returned objects with `first object with ID 2` and only then a `second object with ID 1`. I thought that there were some sort of guarantee that objects are returned already ordered by ID. Should I always call `Room.all.order(:id)` instead of regular `all` method?

```
irb(main):002:0> Room.all
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [
    #<Room id: 2, color: "rgb(83, 180, 83)", status: "Status #2", created_at: "2014-10-11 14:14:02", updated_at: "2014-10-11 14:18:19">, 
    #<Room id: 1, color: "rgb(0, 96, 255)", status: "Status #3", created_at: "2014-10-11 14:14:02", updated_at: "2014-10-11 14:18:30">
  ]>
```

Comment: No cannot be sure about order. I have been using Oracle, PostgreSQL where it does not give ordered record. MySQL seem to return records in sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. `Room.all` just ends up with the SQL `SELECT * FROM rooms;` - no order is there. In this event, the order of the records is determined by the database (for instance, in PostgreSQL, I notice it returns me the most recently updated records last).

If you want to ensure there's an order when you call `.all`, add a default scope which adds it:

```
default_scope order('rooms.id ASC')
```

Comment: Beware of default_scope. Once default_scope of ordering is applied, you cannot apply other ordering directly unless you use `reorder`. Also it varies from database to database how it generates query.